# Converting a "one or many" array to array of arrays in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

Why doesn't the given code compile, and how do I fix it:

```
function f(x: string[] | string[][]): string[][] {
  return Array.isArray(x[0]) ? x : [x];
}
```

As far as I can tell, the return value will always be `string[][]` since of x is `string[]`, `x[0]` will not be an array, and if x is `string[][]` then `x[0]` will be an array.

Even though, typescript doesn't recognize this and throws an array. 
Is there a way to get around it **without casting**? How?

Answer (score 2):

[Type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) will narrow the type of `x` to `string[][]`.

```
function isMatrix(v: any[] | any[][]): v is any[][] {
    return Array.isArray(v[0]);
}

function f(x: string[] | string[][]): string[][] {
  return isMatrix(x) ? x : [x];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgWQIZQE4wB4AUAbgFyIZgCeA2gLqIA+5VddAlGUciszbXYgDeAWABQiCYmwBTKCGxIAgtmwZKAOlTLVlYtQAMtNgG4xAXzFjQkWAkTACeMihwwwAcwFMXuD6yPOrn789CLiUrLySKiYroR4bIgA-Ih4iGTUeLSmomZAA)